How can you tell internal USB controllers (South Bridge) apart from external (Motherboard) controllers?
I recently built a workstation and am running into issues getting Linux to boot. After a lot of trial and error (because mostly the behavior I see is indefinite hangs) I think I've narrowed the issue down to the USB enumeration.
If I am able to boot to Linux, is there a way to discern which USB hubs are internal (to the South Bridge) and which are external on the motherboard?
I am trying to determine if (1) what my options are for fixing the issue and (2) if I should either consider RMAing my SoC (AMD 5975WX) or my motherboard (Asus WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI II).
Surely there is some characteristic of PCIe hierarchy that makes the distinction clear?
What I am able to see from the Linux early boot is
xhci_hcd 0000:23:00.0: init 0000:23:00.0 fail, -16
xhci_hcd 0000:2a:00.1: init 0000:2a:00.1 fail, -16
xhci_hcd 0000:2a:00.3: init 0000:2a:00.3 fail, -16

16 is EBUSY, which sounds like an interesting failure mode. Using this PCI bus enumeration can the origin of the failure be known?

All your USB ports are handled through the WRX80 chipset. If your USB troubles are hardware-related, it’s more likely a motherboard problem than a CPU problem.
(Your CPU isn’t an SoC.)

I suppose maybe pedantically it's not a completely self-contained system. Although I perhaps misspoke by categorizing something that is "more than a processor" but also "less than a complete system" as a SoC.

The main consideration here is that it doesn’t have a USB controller; that’s all on the motherboard.
